# drag and drop li values with image using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am having one `<ul><li>` values with name and image listed on the left div. I want to select each `<li>` values to add to right `<ul> </ul>`. Also I need the functionality to drag and drop these li values.  I tried the follwoing query to drag and drop. But didn't worked out

```
    $("#draggable li").draggable({
        helper:"clone"
    });
    $("#cart ul").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).find("#placeholder")
            $("<li></li>").html(ui.draggable.html()).append(this);
        }
    });
```

Please help on this.

Comment: what does your HTML look like

Comment: <ul id="draggable" style="">
                
                <li><img  height='30px' src="../../Content/images/loger.gif" /><span>Asp.net</span></li>
                <li><img  height='30px' src="../../Content/images/loger.gif" /><span>c#</span></li>
<li><img  height='30px' src="../../Content/images/loger.gif" /><span>SQL Server</span></li>
            </ul>

 <div id="cart">
                        <ul class="up" id="droppable">
                      <li></li>
                        </ul>
                        
                        </div>

Answer (score 1):

Simple drag, drop and double click example is here: [jsfiddle drag and drop](http://jsfiddle.net/qNkC8/5/)

What do you mean by select li?